# PHP next page after info filled in

Tags: php, mysql, appointment

I'm having to make an appointment based system for the student services teachers at my school. So far, I've made a login system and a registration system for both teachers and students.  Now I'm making the booking system.

My appointment table in my PHPMyAdmin database looks like this:

```
id (int 11, A.I)
ss_name (int 11) (this is the teacher name, also in the teacher table)
slot_date (date)
client_student_id (int 11) (student id, also in students table)
slot_line (the line in school timetable for appointment to be made)
reason (varhar)
status (varchar)
```

My problem is that I need to be able to put in a students ID number, the teachers name and be able to go to the next page for that specific teacher.

This is my PHP code:

```
    <?php
     ob_start();
     session_start();
     require_once 'dbconnect.php';

     if( !isset($_SESSION['client']) ) {
      header("Location: homepage_login.php");
      exit;
     }
     // select loggedin users detail
     $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE client_id=".$_SESSION['client']);
     $userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);


     if( isset($_POST['btn-nxt-page']) ) { 

      $client_student_id = $_POST['client_student_id'];
      $ss_name = $_POST['ss_name'];

      $client_student_id = strip_tags(trim($client_student_id));
      $ss_name = strip_tags(trim($ss_name));

      $pass = ($client_student_id);

      $res=mysql_query("SELECT client_student_id, ss_name FROM appointments WHERE client_student_id='$client_student_id'");

      $row=mysql_fetch_array($res);

      $count = mysql_num_rows($res); // if uname/pass correct it returns must be 1 row

      if( $count == 1 && $row['client_student_id']==$pass ) {
       $_SESSION['client'] = $row['ss_name'];
       header("Location: homepage_loggedin_book2.php");
      } else {
       $errMSG = "Wrong Credentials, Try again...";
      }
     }
    ?>
```

And this is my HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group">
             <div class="input-group">
             <input type="text" name="client_student_id" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Student ID" required />
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>

       <label for="ss" id="menu">Select a teacher</label>
            <select name="ss_name" id="#menu">
               <option>John</option>
               <option>Smith</option>
               <option>Greg</option>
               <option>Jess</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <br>

        <div class="form-group">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" name="btn-nxt-page">Next Page</button>
            </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

My major question is:

How do I get the button to redirect to another page with the booking system for a specific teacher who was chosen in my HTML code??

Comment: *"For my school project"* - You need to work for your own marks, not us. This is homework. Nobody ever did my homework and I never expected them to neither.

Comment: You're right, but she's just asking for help. It's a specific question, she's not asking the solution to the whole project..

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use some javascript. Better with jQuery. I'll give you a brief example for this case. But how said in the comments, these are homeworks...

## script

```
<script>
    $(function () {
       $('button[type="submit"]').on('click', function (e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           var url = "http://your_url/" + $('#menu').find(':selected').text();
           window.location.replace(url);
       });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in the php script that handles your form as well using the header() function if you don't want to use javascript.